# How to factor this expression

Tags: factoring

Could someone explain to me the process of factoring this $-6x(x+1)(x^2+2)^{-5/2} + 2(x^2+2)^{-3/2}$ into this $2(1-2x)(x+2)(x^2+2)^{-5/2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Note that  $$2(x^2+2)^{-3/2} = 2(x^2 + 2)(x^2+2)^{-5/2}$$

Now factor out $2(x^2+2)^{-5/2}$ from each term.

Comment: @rlartiga I had already done that, but I don't know how to go from $2(x^2+2)^{-5/2}(-3x(x+1)+(x^2+2)^{3/5})$ to $2(1-2x)(x+2)(x^2+2)^{-5/2}$

Comment: You should have  $$2(x^2+2)^{-5/2}((-3x^2 - 3x)+(x^2+2)) = 2(x^2 + 2)^{-5/2}(-2x^2-3x+2)$$ Can you take it from here? (Note that $(-2x^2 - 3x + 2) = -(2x^2 + 3x - 2) = -(2x +1)(x - 2) = (2-x)(2x+1)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2(x^2+2)^{-5/2}((-3x^2+-3x)+(x^2+2)^{3/5}))$?

Comment: No: $2(x^2+2)^{-3/2} = 2(x^2 + 2)^{2/2}(x^2+2)^{-5/2}$. Factoring out the second factor leaves us $$2(x^2 + 2)^{2/2} = 2(x^2 + 2)$$

Comment: OOPs...I meant $-(2x - 1)(x+2)= (1-2x)(x+2)$ in my post following "Can you take it from here?" comment

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was doing something really silly, that's when you know you need to take a rest haha.

Comment: Ah! Sweet, restorative sleep! I'm making myself sleepy! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$$-6x(x+1)(x^2+2)^{-5/2} + 2(x^2+2)^{-3/2}=(x^2+2)^{-\frac{5}{2}}(-6x(x+1)+2(x^2+2)^{-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{5}{2}})$$